# Home router on Fedora Linux

Tags: fedora, iptables, router

I've got a PCEngines micro PC with 4 ethernet ports, whole point was for it to replace my dying WatchGuard box. I'm not exactly new to Linux Firewalls but this is the first time I've tried anything like this, normally I've only cared about single system with 1 or 2 NICs.

Current setup is

```
ISP Box >(enp1s0)> Linux Box >(enp2s0)> Switch > Server
                                               > Wifi AP
```

with IPTables set up:

```
[root@Firewall ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,8096,8920 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp2s0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlp5s0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp2s0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlp5s0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp2s0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o wlp5s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlp5s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp2s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp2s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

It works, except I'm having some problems with traffic from server to wifi and I need to open 80 and 8096 (soon to be 443 and 8920 when I get SSL setup) to the internet from server which I don't know how to do with it behind the switch. (wifi speed from the PCEngines box was subpar so I've disabled it for now).

If I connected everything to the FW and bridged enp2s0, enp3s0 and enp4s0 was my thought on the better setup, because the forwarding rules I've tried don't seem to work the way I have the switch setup (also changing IPTables seems to lock it up entirely needing a reload rather than a restart and sometimes even requiring a reboot, I'm not sure what's going on there) so I've been reluctant to experiment over and over since it takes me offline every time.

Is a bridge the right way to do this? should I use nmcli to create the bridge or bridge-utils like a lot of the random guides suggest? I know there's better ways to do what I've got for IPTables, but if I do the bridge what do I need to do there?

Comment: Have you considered just using DD-WRT? If it's available for your hardware it would be a lot less painful than rolling your own from scratch

Comment: its a micro PC, so not sure? but I also want to host Sonarr on the box as well as a couple of other things.